# Python: how to save each file obtained from os.walk loop?

Tags: python, html, for-loop, directory, os.walk

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(exampleDirectory):
    for i in files:
        relativePaths = os.path.relpath(exampleDirectory, outputDirectory)
        relativeFiles = os.path.join(relativePaths, i)
```

In the example above, depending on where I put the print statement for relativeFiles, it will print either only the last file if I put it outside the for loop, or it will print all the files if I place it inside the loop.

I would like display all the files on an HTML page, but it will only display the last file since the script for the HTML is outside of the for loop. How can I ensure that all files that are in the os.walk are saved outside of the for loop?

Comment: You can store filenames in a `list` using `append` method.

Comment: Thank you! Although now when I try to use it in html, it returns an error because it tries to print entire list at once, so baby steps figuring it out for me!

Comment: I could write the code for you but you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33920896/table-within-an-html-document-using-python-list) how it works

Comment: The table example is throwing me off but I kinda get what it means, thanks so much!